# Android studio can't see the design?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have been doing it in Android studio for a few days but I have never had such a problem :(

Background  blank only text showing `androidx.constraintlayout....ConstraintLayout`

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Gradle file**

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVUWo.jpg)

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
    belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: Can you post your XML code here?

Comment: @ShailendraMadda I have changed the image, in that you will see a `xml file`

Comment: Can you add the code in the question itself instead of an image? There is nothing to display in the design as it contains only ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Looks like there is no issue in your XML, just try to update the `ConstraintLayout` dependency sync and try it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's related to the Gradle script file version issue just see your dependencies and change if it is outdated.. maybe this can help?

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

and sync it !!

Comment: maybe I need to send Gradle file then maybe you can help us

Comment: Just update the dependencies of the constraint layout or can copy the above dependencies.. and it can help !!.. if it helps accept my answer, Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Update your `Constraintlayout` dependency in your app level `build.gradle` and check:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
```

Comment: I'm also using `2.1.3`

Comment: have you clicked on sync after updating it? is your build success?

Comment: ok it is working but this problem is also coming in the coordinator layout

Comment: Great then accept the answer if it helps. Try to update `androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0` as well

Comment: sorry again the same problem is coming

Comment: `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.`

Comment: What is your Gradle version? can you post your project level `build.gradle` file and update your question?

Comment: Try to use this gradle version in your project level build.gradle file.
`classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"`